# Why does the ExpectedConditions invisibilityOfElementLocated work using element ID but fail using the Classname for the preloader?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to wait till the preloader appears on the website for that I'm using ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated but initially when I was locating preloader through the class name "DarkBg", the explicit wait didn't wait for the preloader to get invisible but later when I located through Id then the explicit wait worked and waited till the loader disappeared.

I've attached the loader image along with its source code. I want to know why the explicit wait through classname locator didn't work?

[image: Preloader]

Comment: How many occurrences of class DarkBg are on your page?

Comment: As mentioned by @SiKing, Have you got a chance to check how many elements are there on the page with the class `DarkBg`. Possibility is there may be another element with the same class name.

Comment: There is only one instance of Class DarkBg, which I found using  System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.className("DarkBg")).size());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using *ExpectedConditions* `invisibilityOfElementLocated()` with the *classname* **DarkBg**, the element seems to be a `<div>` node which seems to be the parent of the actual **overlay** in the form of the `<img>` node. This `<div>` node includes only the **`style`** `height` and may be either bigger then the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) (or out of the Viewport) and can be the possible reason behind [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) unable to interact with it:

[image: div_img]

Where as the `<img>` tag seems to be have all the required **`style`** attributes present to be within the *Viewport* and interactable in the form of `width`, `height`, `top`, etc.

Hence *Selenium* easily detects it.